# Read query using PlayOrm does return appropriate results

Tags: cassandra, playorm

I have just started exploring PlayOrm and trying to run a basic code available on the net to insert and read data. When I insert data, everything appears to be working fine, but on reading the same data it returns me incorrect number of rows. For eg. if I insert 3 records I get 0 records sometimes and sometimes all the records are returned.

Following the code I am using:

The class used for inserting/reading data:

```
  @NoSqlEntity
  @NoSqlQueries({
    @NoSqlQuery(name="findByLastName", query="PARTITIONS t('lastName',:lastName) select *  FROM TABLE as t"),
    @NoSqlQuery(name="findByName", query="PARTITIONS e('name',:name) select *  FROM TABLE as e")
  })

  public class User {

    @NoSqlId
    private String id;

    @NoSqlPartitionByThisField
    private String name;

    @NoSqlIndexed
    private int age;

    @NoSqlPartitionByThisField
    @NoSqlIndexed
    private String lastName;

    public String getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

    public int getAge() {
            return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    /*
     * Queries:
     *      @NoSqlQuery(name="findByLastName", query="PARTITIONS t('lastName',:lastName) select *  FROM TABLE as t"),
     *      @NoSqlQuery(name="findByName", query="PARTITIONS e('name',:name) select *  FROM TABLE as e")
     */

    public static List<User> findByLastName(NoSqlEntityManager mgr, String lastName) {
            Query<User> query = mgr.createNamedQuery(User.class, "findByLastName");
            System.out.println("Using last name "+lastName);
            query.setParameter("lastName", lastName);
            return query.getResultList(0, 100);
    }

    public static List<User> findByName(NoSqlEntityManager mgr, String name) {
            Query<User> query = mgr.createNamedQuery(User.class, "findByName");
            System.out.println("Using name "+name);
            query.setParameter("name", name);
            return query.getResultList(0, 100);
    }

  }
```

The code that makes use of this class:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.base.DbTypeEnum;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.base.NoSqlEntityManager;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.base.NoSqlEntityManagerFactory;
import com.netflix.astyanax.retry.SleepingRetryPolicy;

public class Example {

private static NoSqlEntityManager mgr;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put(Bootstrap.AUTO_CREATE_KEY, "create");
    /*
     * Bootstrap.createAndAddBestCassandraConfiguration(properties, clusterName, keyspace, seeds);
     * NoSqlEntityManagerFactory factory = Bootstrap.create(DbTypeEnum.CASSANDRA, properties,null,null);
     */
    NoSqlEntityManagerFactory factory = Bootstrap.create(DbTypeEnum.IN_MEMORY, properties,null,null);
    mgr = factory.createEntityManager();


   String file_to_use = userData;
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
   System.out.println("Starting inserts with file "+file_to_use+" at "+sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

   BufferedReader CSVFile = null;
   try {
        CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_to_use));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     String dataRow = null;
    try {
        dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // Read the first line of data.
      int i = 0; 
      while (dataRow != null){
          String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");
          User user = new User();
          user.setName(dataArray[0]);
          user.setAge(Integer.parseInt(dataArray[1]));
          user.setLastName(dataArray[2]);
          System.out.println("Inserting Values "+dataArray[0]+" "+dataArray[1]+" "+dataArray[2]);


          mgr.flush();
          try {
            dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

     java.util.List<User> result;
     System.out.println("#### By LastName ####");
     result = User.findByLastName(mgr, "Freida");
     System.out.println("Result Size: "+ result.size());

     System.out.println("#### By Time ####");
     result = User.findByName(mgr, "John");
     System.out.println("Result Size: "+ result.size());
}
}
```

Contents of User Data:

```
John,17,Freida
Jim,18,Freida
Jam,19,Freida
Johny,20,Freida
Jen,21,Freida
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This was a very specific bug in PlayOrM.  A committed fix is in the latest here https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/commit/22d50a12667d03fd2c4683abeb59a4822420a4ce

It only occurs when you use both @NoSqlPartionedBy and @NoSqlIndexed on the same columns twice.  One work around is to put something in your where clause(anything) and it will use the specific index instead every time(based on the column in your where clause).  Or just get the latest code with the fix.

I am not sure you should be using partitions at all.  In your example you are partitioning your table in two ways....name and lastName.  In one case, all rows with the same name go in the same partition.  In the other case, all rows with the same lastName go in the same partition.  You can only query a single partition.  So imagine you have names

```
dean
mike
joe
```

These are 3 different partitions and you can query into anyone.  You could query "give me all the people with lastname=smith in partition=dean" OR you could query give me all the people with lastname=smith in partition=mike"

Imagine you also had the lastNames

```
smith
black
obama
```

You have 3 partitions here and you could query "give me all the people with name=dean in the partition=smith" or "give me all the people with the name=dean in the partition=black"

IF you want to make things easier, get rid of all the @NoSqlPartitionByField so you don't partition at all.

Basically, with partitioning, you can query a single partition.  Each partition is it's own index.  This is why it can scale as you have infinite partitions of X million rows.  You cannot have infinite rows in a partition though.

I am guessing alot though as your example only inserts ONE row while you claim to be inserting 3 rows and I would expect your code in both cases to return 1 row.  Your queries ask to return ALL rows for the partition where lastName="Frieda" and then all rows in the partition where name="John" and since you stored an object with both, that is the partitions that row should end up in....this works for us in production already and we have had no issues with it.

let me know if you have more info like the code that does 3 insertions instead of just this one.

Dean

Comment: I had created partitions on these fields since I wanted the queries on these fields to perform very fast. Will having just an index on these fields help us to attain same objective? (Considering the number of different names for same last name to be 50k and different possible last name for same names be around 20k)

Also in the above code, I had inserted 2 more records with name Jim and Jam with same last name Freida. So I was expecting 3 records in response to the query on last name

Comment: show me the code that is not working and we can cut and paste and run it as well(are you using in-memory version for this example or cassandra....they work the same but just wanted to know just in case).   Edit your post with the code that is not working.  Also, 50k for same last name...that is not the info I would be interested in to make a decision on what you should do.  The info needed is total row count ;).  You can go into the millions just fine without partitions.  Limit maybe is 3 million(I have been at 1 million before).  beyond needs partitioning.

Comment: I have edited the code above. I am running exactly the same code. Try if it works for you. Also, for the row count info, I guess if we partition by lastname, since we have 50K different last names, we would have 50k rows and same is the case for names. I might be wrong in using the partitioning logic to calculate row count. If you want to know how many different User records (User with different value in user.id field) would exist in DB then it would be 50k*20k = 1 billion. Let me know if I am wrong somewhere

Comment: great, in-memory or cassandra?  I will have vikas take a look at this exact example.  Let me confirm that you expect the findByLast to return 5 results and you expect findByName to return 1 result, is that correct? (That is what I expect).  Also, your example has no other last names so there will only be one partition when looking at lastname partitions.  For firstname partitions, there is 5 partitions all with one row in them.  This is what you are expecting, correct?

Comment: Exactly! That is what I am expecting. I tried out things with out partitioning also. I don't see any problems with that. Its working all fine.

Comment: I just noticed your above code is missing a mgr.put(user) before the mgr.flush();  I am going to have vikas run the code tonight and debug if it's an issue.  Make sure you have mgr.put(user).

Comment: Yes I have mgr.put in the code I am running! During some editing it must have got missed out! Just for added info I am using following jars:
`playorm-1.4.4.jar`
`astyanax-1.56.26.jar`
`slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar`
`guice-3.0.jar`
`javax.inject-1.jar`
`antlr-runtime-3.3.jar`
`javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar`
`joda-time-2.0.jar`
`org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-csv-1.0-r706900_3.jar`
`commons-codec-1.5.jar`
`uuid-3.2.0.jar`

Comment: I ran the code and the results are coming sometime and sometime not. This is really a weird behavior and seems to be a defect. Looking more into it.

Comment: ah, so this bug was some code we put in to not burden any "one" index on a query of ALL entities in the partition.  If you add something to your where clause, it works 100% of the time as it then uses that index every time.  In the meantime, we are fixing it.  This bug will only occur when there is no where clause(so we don't know which index to use and pick one randomly and unfortunatley, pick the column that is the partition key).

Comment: still actively working, close to being fixed, sorry for the delay.

Comment: try the latest code...fix was commited here https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/commit/22d50a12667d03fd2c4683abeb59a4822420a4ce